# Mongoose .save() -- TypeError: _this[i].emit is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When attempting to save a document this error is thrown:

```
/Users/home/Documents/web/thp/modules/thp_db/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:98
process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                              ^

TypeError: _this[i].emit is not a function
at EventEmitter.notify (/Users/home/Documents/web/thp/modules/thp_db/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/documentarray.js:238:18)
at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:169:7)
at Document.(anonymous function) [as emit] (/Users/home/Documents/web/thp/modules/thp_db/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:93:44)
at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/home/Documents/web/thp/modules/thp_db/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/embedded.js:31:15)
at emitTwo (events.js:92:20)
at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
at model.Document.(anonymous function) [as emit] (/Users/home/Documents/web/thp/modules/thp_db/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:93:44)
at /Users/home/Documents/web/thp/modules/thp_db/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:227:11
at /Users/home/Documents/web/thp/modules/thp_db/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:135:7
at /Users/home/Documents/web/thp/modules/thp_db/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:504:5
at /Users/home/Documents/web/thp/modules/thp_db/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:666:5
at handleCallback (/Users/home/Documents/web/thp/modules/thp_db/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:96:12)
at /Users/home/Documents/web/thp/modules/thp_db/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/unordered.js:473:9
at handleCallback (/Users/home/Documents/web/thp/modules/thp_db/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:96:12)
at resultHandler (/Users/home/Documents/web/thp/modules/thp_db/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/unordered.js:420:5)
at commandCallback (/Users/home/Documents/web/thp/modules/thp_db/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:1246:9)
at Callbacks.emit (/Users/home/Documents/web/thp/modules/thp_db/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:119:3)
at null.messageHandler (/Users/home/Documents/web/thp/modules/thp_db/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:397:23)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/home/Documents/web/thp/modules/thp_db/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:302:22)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:153:18)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:111:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:536:20)
```

Code leading to save looks like this:

```
var db = req.app.locals.db;
var league = new db.League();

// league is populated here

// ================
// GIVE LEAGUE _id (auto increment)
// ================
db.Counter.findByIdAndUpdate('League',
                             { $inc: { n: 1 } },
                             { new: true },
    function(err, counter){
        if(err) return log.error('League _id set error', err);

        league._id = counter.n;

        // ================
        // INTO DB: CODE RUNS TO HERE
        // ================

        league.save(function(err, new_league) {

            // DOES NOT REACH HERE!

            if (err) {
                log.error('league DB entry error:', err);
                return res.status(200).end('Error creating league');
            }

            console.log('SAVED LEAGUE', util.inspect(new_league, false, null));

            res.status(200).end('Thank you');
        });
    }
);
```

Strange thing is that this worked fine last night, and unless I sleepwalked and logged in, nothing was changed.

the `db` variable is a collection of models.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How did you define `db.League`?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that the error is thrown depending on which inputs of the submission form are filled out. Haven't the time to determine which exactly at the moment, but will update here when I do.

**UPDATE**: my `league` var was populated by a JSON object parsed from incoming form data. One of the properties was thoughtlessly called `.on`, which was fooling with the standard event listening notation `.on`. Silly mistake! Always is.